# how to change div width based on content

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to figure out how to display my divs on a single row and change their width.
If the image div doesn't exist, the description div should have `width: 100%` (or in my case col-12).
How can I change the width?

```
 <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div *ngFor="let update of updates">
            <p class="font-weight-bold">{{update.title}}</p>
            <div class="col-9">
                <p>{{update.description}}</p>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="update.imageUrl" class="col-3">
                <img src="{{update.imageUrl}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: By giving the description-div a col-9 or col-12 with an *ngIf="update.imageUrl" (Im not familiar with the actual syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ngClass` directive and set classes conditionally.

```
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div *ngFor="let update of updates">
            <p class="font-weight-bold">{{update.title}}</p>
            <div [ngClass]="(update.imageUrl)?'col-9':'col-12'">
                <p>{{update.description}}</p>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="update.imageUrl" class="col-3">
                <img src="{{update.imageUrl}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**[Here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description) is the reference.**